# mean/median age for each US zip code

Tags: us-census, demographics, postal-code, database

I need a table that will map each US zip code to either the mean age or the median age of the population in that zip code.

I see that https://www.census.gov/popest/data/counties/asrh/2015 provides estimates of this data at the county level.  I am ok with estimated data, but I need to be able to look up the data by zip code.

Alternatively, perhaps there is a way to get the info from the census demographic profile (http://www2.census.gov/census_2010/03-Demographic_Profile/), but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a quick export of data from the 2014 5-year ACS of the population and median age of every ZIP code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/utnthc601i82iff/census.csv?dl=0

Comment: Data need met. Fish provided. Bonus points for teaching them how to fish...

Comment: How do I view it? It's asking for things about snowflake

Comment: @dranxo I just swapped the link out for one that works. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

American Fact Finder includes median age in their General Population and Housing Statistics reports;
[General Population and Housing Statistics for Zip Code 23662](http://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/DEC/10_DP/DPDP1/8600000US23662) is one such table, from the 2010 US Census.
To get them all: not sure if American Fact Finder offers bulk download, but almost positive they do; if for some reason that is not an option, find a list of all US zip codes, and swap them out in the URL; the above example actually points to: `http://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/DEC/10_DP/DPDP1/8600000US23662`
`US23662` is the zip code variable being used, replace/append zip codes as desired.

Comment: This is a nice rest based approach. I didn't know about that api option. useful.

Comment: Here's a direct link to B01002 Median Age by Sex for all ZCTAs in the US, 2012-2016 ACS https://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/16_5YR/B01002/0100000US.86000 -- here's the link to the Decennial census as @albert linked to, but for all ZCTA in US and only Median Age by Sex https://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/DEC/10_SF1/P13/0100000US.86000

Comment: @JoeGermuska thanks for sharing. why do the URLs redirect? i find that to be incredibly confusing.

Comment: @albert I wish I knew. Consistent bookmarkable and editable URLs should be given for data which doesn't change.